# CSS: cannot access dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a dropdown navigation bar, but I keep getting problems with being able to access the drop down menu. The menu itself will display fine, the problem comes when I want to access the drop down menu: as soon as I move my cursor off the buttons that unhides the dropdown list, the dropdown list itself disappears.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNGqvp

CSS:

```
#navigation li {
  display:          inline;
}

/*navigation text*/
.nav a
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background:#383838;
    border-radius: 2em;
    border: 1px solid #272727;
    color:#C4B09C;
    text-decoration:none;
    font: bold 12px Arial;
    line-height: 27px;
    margin-right:1 px;
    position: relative;
    left: 250px;
    top: 7px; 
}


/*naviagation menu*/
.nav  {
    background: #333; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#383838, #272727);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#383838), to(#272727)); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#383838, #272727);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}




/*menu hover*/
.nav li >ul {display : none;}

.nav li:hover > ul  {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="nav">
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Media</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="audio.html">Audio</a></li>
                <li><a href="video.html">Video</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="honesty.html">Honesty</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do  is add `width: 100%` to the `.nav :hover`.  That way, you are still technically hovering the navigation bar, when you go to click on the sub-navigation items.

This is tried and true - example here:

### http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYwpdN

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! Why exactly does that method work? What is it doing?

Comment: This "works", but the menu stays when you move to the right or left of it.

Comment: your mouse was leaving the "hover" state because the sub-elements were too far away. Setting the width to 100% makes it possible to move the mouse down and still be over the sub-element, maintaining the hover state of the parent element. If you want the sub-elements to dis-appear when you would need to move your mouse down below to the element. Or you can change the size and position of the elements.

Comment: Yes, @Isubi's answer is correct.  You were no longer hovering the menu because the elements were too far away.  I made the element bigger, so that you were hovering all the way to your sub-navigation elements.

Comment: I do find the .nav a CSS style confusing though, as this sets all a elements in the menu to left:250px. This makes things hard to keep aligned. It's going to give you trouble. I prefer to place elements relative to each other.

Comment: Yes.  As @Isubi just mentioned, you could align your a elements better.